# Synchronizing jQuery setInterval for slideshow

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshow, setinterval

I created a very basic slideshow by repeating the `jQuery` effects with `setInterval`. However, there is a mismatch in timing after each cycle of the `setInterval`. After a few cycles, it leads to a visible mismatch in two parallel slide effects.

The code is

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var frontslides =$("#first li").length,
    slideTime=500,
    slideCycle=parseInt(slideTime*frontslides);

function frontSlide(){
    $("#first li").each(function(n){
        $(this).delay(slideTime*n).fadeIn(400).fadeOut(100);
        $("#second li").eq(n).delay(slideTime*n).fadeIn(400).fadeOut(100);
    });}
frontSlide();setInterval(frontSlide, slideCycle);});​
```

The working example is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zrmyY/)

To save your valuable time, its speed is fast, but it happens on any speed. After a few cycles, you can see that left and right slides are no longer synchronized.

Comment: `setInterval()` and `setTimeout()` are not guaranteed to run "on time", as Javascript is single-threaded and at times it runs when it can, not at a specific timing.

Comment: @JaredFarrish then what is your recommendation for unlimited repeats? e.g. for slideshows?

Comment: What you're doing seems really convoluted. If I can rework it to show what I'd do, I'll do that, I just hope I have the same interpretation you do for what you're after.

Comment: @JaredFarrish I cannot claim to be an expert in javascript, but I do not see any unconventional process in the code. I would learn if you give me a hint what is the straightforward approach to implement this JS process.

Comment: I'm having technical difficulties; my browser keeps crashing.

Comment: Also, are you use jQuery 1.4.4 on purpose?

Comment: @JaredFarrish no, I just had no use for new functions introduced after jQuery 1.4.4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### First approach: setTimeout

You could move the transitioning to the next slide in a separate function and call it with `setTimeout`. Then, you just store the slide number in a variable and increment it after each function call.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var firstSlides = $("#first li"),
        secondSlides = $("#second li"),
        nbSlides = firstSlides.length,
        slideTime = 500,
        nextSlide = 0;

    function slideshow() {
        firstSlides.eq(nextSlide).fadeIn(400).fadeOut(100);
        secondSlides.eq(nextSlide).fadeIn(400).fadeOut(100);

        nextSlide = (nextSlide+1) % nbSlides;
        setTimeout(slideshow, slideTime);
    }

    slideshow();
});
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MattiasBuelens/mnygF/) of this first approach.

### Second approach: promises

If you want to **absolutely guarantee** that both animations are completed when starting the next animation, you can use the new promises from jQuery 1.6. You can call [`$.promise()`](http://api.jquery.com/promise/) on both jQuery objects to get a promise which will be resolved when all animations of that element are completed. Then, you can set up a master promise with `$.when(promises...)` which will be resolved when all the given promises are resolved and set up a `then` handler.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var firstSlides = $("#first li"),
        secondSlides = $("#second li"),
        nbSlides = firstSlides.length,
        fadeInTime = 400,
        fadeOutTime = 100,
        nextSlide = 0;

    function slideIn() {
        var p1 = firstSlides.eq(nextSlide).fadeIn(400).promise();
        var p2 = secondSlides.eq(nextSlide).fadeIn(400).promise();

        $.when(p1, p2).then(slideOut);
    }

    function slideOut() {
        var p1 = firstSlides.eq(nextSlide).fadeOut(100).promise();
        var p2 = secondSlides.eq(nextSlide).fadeOut(100).promise();

        nextSlide = (nextSlide+1) % nbSlides;

        $.when(p1, p2).then(slideIn);
    }

    slideIn();
});
```

For a simple slideshow, you probably won't notice much of a difference. However, with promises you can make much more advanced transition sequences with funky timings while still maintaining synchronisation.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MattiasBuelens/pK8Br/) of that approach.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Thanks, didn't actually check the HTML of the OP.

Answer (score 2):

Set the animations to both run at the "same" time:

```
function frontSlide(){
    $("#first li").each(function(n){
        var _ = $(this);
        setTimeout(function() {
            _.fadeIn(400).fadeOut(100);
            $("#second li").eq(n).fadeIn(400).fadeOut(100);
        }, slideTime*n);
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you chain `$.fadeIn()` and `$.fadeOut()` without them colliding in timings, ie, run concurrently?

Comment: +1 Good point. Don't you want to use `fadeOut` inside `fadeIn`'s callback?

Comment: You can chain effects on the same element - jQuery will run effects consecutively if they're on the same element (see http://api.jquery.com/queue/ - about 30% down)

Answer (score 1):

Since I opened my mouth, here is the version I came up with. I added a `blocked` flag in there to indicate an effects loop was currently running, hopefully preventing the script from overrunning itself. I also added a `factor` value so that if overrunning did occur, it would loop more quickly, to preserve the appearance that the loop was not disrupted.

If you have any other questions about it, just let me know. It's pretty straight forward.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $sel = $('#left, #right').find('li:first-child'),
        slidetime = 200,
        timein = 400,
        timeout = 100,
        blocked = false;

    var fadeout = function() {
        $sel.fadeOut(timeout, next);
    };

    var next = function() {
        if ($sel.is(':last-child')) {
            $sel = $sel.siblings(':first-child');
        } else {
            $sel = $sel.next();
        }

        blocked = false;
    };

    (function slider() {
        var factor = .2;

        if (!blocked) {
            factor = 1;
            blocked = true;

            $sel.fadeIn(timein, fadeout);
        }

        setTimeout(slider, slidetime * factor);
    })();
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/j63vH/

Comment: Thanks for your kind promise! I learned a lot, and just have a question to enhance my knowledge. Your code is more complicated than those suggested by others (several if statements). What is the advantage of this code over simple ones suggested by others?

Comment: The biggest, most significant takeaway you need to notice is that I'm caching jQuery selector objects, ie, `$sel = $('#left, #right')`. Repeatedly querying in an animation is sure, slow, herky-jerky death for your animation. Where possible, cache. The first `if` within the `next` function simply determines if I need to restart at the first `li` element, or move to the next. The second, in the `slider()` function, simply determines if there is a blocking action occurring (an animation), and if not, start an animation sequence and block the next. The rest is just about compartmentalization.

Comment: Also note, `$('#left, #right').find('li:first-child')` seems odd, but realize that I'm getting two different columns in one selector result, then *in each column/list* getting both `li:first-child` elements (to start the animation). It does not work if you take them out, you get one `li:first-child`, which is `#left` in this case. Layout-wise it feels a little noisy, but go through one line at a time and you'll notice my checks and balances take up the most space; the slider-related parts are just a few lines, fewer if I could find a way to automatically restart a selector collection result.